# Grab the correct data upon checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My viewmodel:

```
  function AddEmployeesViewModel() {
    var self=this;
    self.names=ko.observableArray();
  } 

  AddEmployeesViewModel.prototype.addEmployee=function(){
     ???
  };

$.getJSON('/xxx.json').then(function(data){   
        addEmployeesViewModel.names([]);
        for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
          addEmployeesViewModel.names.push({id:data[i].id,name:data[i].name});
        } 
      },
        function(){
          console.log('failure');
        }
     );


var addEmployeesViewModel=new AddEmployeesViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(addEmployeesViewModel);
```

and my model:

```
<div>
  <!-- ko foreach: names -->
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.addEmployee"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

My problem is to make addEmployee function to return the **id corresponding to the name** every time we select a checkbox. Which is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) doesn't take a callback, it takes an observable, which it will set to true or false depending on the state of the checkbox.

From your description, it looks like you want to handle a `click` on the checkbox, and if it is checked, do something with the associated data item.

```js
vm = {
  addEmployee: function(data, event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.debug("Do something with", data.id);
    }
    return true;
  },
  names: ko.observableArray([{
    name: 'one',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'two',
    id: 2
  }])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- ko foreach: names -->
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.addEmployee"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```